# Cygwin: "-bash: make: command not found"

Tags: c++, terminal, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to use cygwin as my compiler and for some reason it's not working. I followed this video on how to install it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRbbDkDb5UM

then I followed this video on how to use it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKOcnRDGFLw

When I made my first program "Hello world" and tried the command "make hello," I'm getting the error "-bash: make: command not found." Any ideas what's wrong?

Here's my system path in case there's something wrong with that.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Trend Micro\AMSP;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\
```

Comment: `make` not `Make` if you are writing your own makefile.

Comment: @EtanReisner yeah that was a typo in the title, I used a lower case m.

Comment: Did you start a new cygwin shell after installing everything? Did you install the make package like that first video said?

Comment: @EtanReisner, What do you mean by a new shell? Yeah I installed the make package like the video said, however I couldn't find the exact "openssl" package so I just search openssl and clicked every openssl i could find. Not sure if that make's a difference though.

Comment: ***What do you mean by a new shell*** A new instance of cygwin terminal would give you a new shell.

Comment: @drescherjm, as in just closing and reopening cygwin? I just tried that, still the same error.

Comment: Is `c:\cygwin64\bin` the correct path? Can you find a `make.exe` binary in there?

Comment: @EtanReisner, Not sure if it's the correct path, I followed the video exactly as it told me to. I am inexperience when it comes to this. Would I just add in `make.exe` into the path?

Comment: The video used `c:\cygwin\bin` not `c:\cygwin64\bin`. You should just be able to check if you have that path and if `make.exe` exists under it.

Comment: I would look at that folder in explorer. Also you may want to turn off "Hide file extensions for known types" in explorer so it does not confuse you.

Comment: @EtanReisner Oops, yeah the 64 part is correct, I attempted to install cygwin before and I was told to add that part in. When i check the properties in cygwin, in the target slot, it gives me `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -`

@drescherjm How do I turn that off? I dont see an option for that.

Comment: So do you have a `c:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe` binary? Do you have a `c:\cygwin` directory at all? That's a Windows Explorer setting @drescherjm was talking about there.

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10570-file-extensions-hide-show.html

Comment: @EtanReisner Actually I don't, all i have is a `c:\cygwin64\bin\makeinfo.exe`Wouldn't this have been installed if I followed the video? How do I go about installing that now?

Comment: Re-run the cygwin setup.exe and make sure you select the make package you want to install.

Comment: @EtanReisner I've tried installing the make package at least 3 times and it still won't appear under cgywin64\bin, I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Does setup claim it is installing it? What does the log say is happening?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah, it claims it is downloading and installing. I think i finally figured out what is wrong, the default folders in which it downloads and installs to is different from all the guides I've check. I'm currently installing the packages again and will you let know if it works.

Comment: @EtanReisnerYup that did it... I feel so stupid. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: If you install the 64 bit version `setup-x86_64.exe` the default cygwin install folder is `c:/cygwin64`. If you install the 32 bit version `setup-x86.exe` the default install folder will be `c:/cygwin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.May be problem with `PATH` if you use windows.
2.Try `mingw32-make` instead of make

Comment: What kind of problem? Please be more specific. And... well, I am 99.990815% sure the OS is Windows. Because of the system path in the question.

Comment: You need to add path of the mingw32-make.exe file.